# In MongoDB, possible to find all objects based on their _id?

Tags: mongodb

i would like to find all elements of my collection based on their id number (only using a part of this number for the search):

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
 db.collection.find({"_id":/25/})
```

Comment: It's an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) and not a "string", so regular expressions would not apply. Still it would be possible using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), but just not advisable. Also not really seeing the practicality. Perhaps instead you want to find ObjectId values within a "range".

Comment: @BlakesSeven **If** it's an `ObjectId`. `{_id:"25"}` is a valid document and the regex works fine.

Comment: @AlexBlex, i just tested it does not work

Comment: @BlackesSeven How would you use $where in this case ?

Comment: @AlexBlex Pretty sure that is not what is being asked here. With content like `{ "_id": ObjectId("56d809d013e7859ee995452a") }` then something like `db.collection.find(function() { return /56/.test(this._id.valueOf()) }))` works, but as said it's just impractical. Providing a "range" of values starting with `56` ( or probably more realtically the hex conversion of the timestamp value instead ), now that might just have some use.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, yes. Sorry I messed 'and not a "string"' in your comment =)

Comment: @BlakesSeven, your solution works, thanks !!

Comment: I'm sure it does. Just not sure why on earth you would want this.

Comment: It's to validate a challenge on root- me.org => NoSQL injection

Comment: @BlakesSeven To understand more clearly your solution. Does "this" refers to the collection or to a document ? If it's to a document, which specific one does it refers to ?

Answer (score 0):

It works **only if `_id` is a string**:

Consider a collection:

```
db.test.insert([
    {_id:"123", val:1},
    {_id:"256", val:2},
    {_id:"125", val:3},
    {_id:255, val:4}
]);
```

The query `db.test.find({_id:/25/})` returns only 2 documents:

```
{
    "_id" : "125",
    "val" : 3
},
{
    "_id" : "256",
    "val" : 2
}
```

Comment: Intriguing why you would think this is an answer after the OP already commented *"@AlexBlex, i just tested it does not work"*. Looks more like a fishing trip.

Comment: It's just too long for a comment. I probably had to edit the question to emphasise the OPs `_id` is not a string instead.